# How to make align text to top in css table cell

Tags: html, css

I have the the html table like here

```css
   .table {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: table;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
 display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.row.header {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ea6153;
}
.row.green {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.row.blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .row {
 padding: 8px 0;
 display: block;
  }
}

.cell {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
 padding: 2px 12px;
 display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="row header green">
   <div class="cell">

   </div>
   <div class="cell">
  Name
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
  Id
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
  Author
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
  Price
   </div>
 </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P0aVrLO7Wxob0dIBx80m85wUyHFiK3-Xw7Xw_6CDFAogdeoRR0YWnSjkFNOR4M7nIA=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Flightradar24 - Flight Tracker</h1>
    <span>com.flightradar24pro</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.flightradar24pro
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Flightradar24 AB
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $3.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JXJb3299C15MfJGA0wWoNCq-qNdNOuTXLuvd8mg0Wa3VRTPIDlPMfmUZK-Sn8WLiPz0=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>WatchMaker Premium Watch Face</h1>
    <span>slide.watchFrenzy.premium</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    slide.watchFrenzy.premium
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    androidslide
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $3.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/a125TbrsUMdstTX1UQDPlrIQkFphGp9SQpT30sE8vsEkBj33YulEgaeN8rmmgL5ngk0=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Ski Tracks</h1>
    <span>com.corecoders.skitracks</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.corecoders.skitracks
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Core Coders Ltd
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $0.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WcL0Crw46EJubniXfwCZbVgO7JF9ToVjVjPwlqCqZOhLWtrp8mGjaoh865ZXdhiG1A=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Weather Timeline - Forecast</h1>
    <span>com.samruston.weather</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.samruston.weather
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Sam Ruston
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $1.49
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dsQKC-6sq0rJZX3I1N5ivpU3fS8s-mokRlZnV8gDI9tIdt523j2df8AwwMHVGkvG76Q=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Unified Remote Full</h1>
    <span>com.Relmtech.RemotePaid</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.Relmtech.RemotePaid
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Unified Intents
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $0.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/YmbOfBlKGDy7K39ngf5m0vrXG8gK-gCORC1ybbtMVJa63MX1SPjtxi4jMQmRrcazgw=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>NOAA Weather Unofficial (Pro)</h1>
    <span>com.nstudio.weatherhere</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.nstudio.weatherhere
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Granite Apps
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $1.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HB1NQpjlT21nGLFXCc5lLHXqtft9CHNq8nLW16DDJF_d61_9CVYbEuRfrYGfIXI8V2Y=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Password Manager SafeInCloud™</h1>
    <span>com.safeincloud</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.safeincloud
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    SafeInCloud
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $2.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/twhd0ckGPSETQH7TDkiYvrJr-FKQ-YP1Bll1_-Dk-1Bx4YdJJ1HwinVhHk6uy_YYEe8=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Talon for Twitter</h1>
    <span>com.klinker.android.twitter_l</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.klinker.android.twitter_l
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Luke Klinker
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $1.49
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/UgItAs4ckdGHTXTVWNQ0NNrWy9rh6ya4BrjwAUPMsgMpwOI2NQ7N0zvfQ8eyb78NzHE=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Watch Face - Minimal &amp; Elegant</h1>
    <span>com.stmp.minimalface</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.stmp.minimalface
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Studio eXtreme
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $1.59
  </div>
   </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OZQhEH8B9PNGPkOlx714tIK0mEjMBHUEoJdb2bqUY01i9SKh8iI66j9RMRRzYCvKpYc=w340" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>Weather Live</h1>
    <span>com.apalon.weatherlive</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    com.apalon.weatherlive
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Apalon Apps
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    $0.99
  </div>
   </div>
 
  </div>
```

And then detail css like here :

The problem i got was when I combine the cell with the image the result table would like this picture :
[image: html table]

So how to make the text to align in top? so the red area would be clear. Thanks

The js fiddle detail you can see this link
[html table jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p55ovdp8/)

Comment: Add ```vertical-align: top;``` to ```.cell``` and reduce ```h1``` margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `vertical-align:top`

```
.cell {
   padding: 6px 6px;
   display: table-cell;
   line-height: 1.2em;
   vertical-align:top;
}
.cell h1 {
   margin-top:4px;
}
```

check with the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bc7rf85k/4/

Comment: if he will use margin-top:0px then heading will directly stick, which should not look better..we can use 4 px for better looking right?

Comment: Thanks @JishnuVS it works :D. Leothelion thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: table;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.row.header {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ea6153;
}
.row.green {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.row.blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .row {
    padding: 8px 0;
    display: block;
  }
}

.cell {
   padding: 6px 6px;
   display: table-cell;
   line-height: 1.2em;
   vertical-align:top;
}
.cell h1 {
   margin-top:4px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
    padding: 2px 12px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
        <div class="row header green">
          <div class="cell">

          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            Name
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            Id
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            Author
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            Price
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P0aVrLO7Wxob0dIBx80m85wUyHFiK3-Xw7Xw_6CDFAogdeoRR0YWnSjkFNOR4M7nIA=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Flightradar24 - Flight Tracker</h1>
              <span>com.flightradar24pro</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.flightradar24pro
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Flightradar24 AB
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $3.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JXJb3299C15MfJGA0wWoNCq-qNdNOuTXLuvd8mg0Wa3VRTPIDlPMfmUZK-Sn8WLiPz0=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>WatchMaker Premium Watch Face</h1>
              <span>slide.watchFrenzy.premium</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              slide.watchFrenzy.premium
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              androidslide
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $3.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/a125TbrsUMdstTX1UQDPlrIQkFphGp9SQpT30sE8vsEkBj33YulEgaeN8rmmgL5ngk0=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Ski Tracks</h1>
              <span>com.corecoders.skitracks</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.corecoders.skitracks
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Core Coders Ltd
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $0.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WcL0Crw46EJubniXfwCZbVgO7JF9ToVjVjPwlqCqZOhLWtrp8mGjaoh865ZXdhiG1A=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Weather Timeline - Forecast</h1>
              <span>com.samruston.weather</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.samruston.weather
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Sam Ruston
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $1.49
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dsQKC-6sq0rJZX3I1N5ivpU3fS8s-mokRlZnV8gDI9tIdt523j2df8AwwMHVGkvG76Q=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Unified Remote Full</h1>
              <span>com.Relmtech.RemotePaid</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.Relmtech.RemotePaid
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Unified Intents
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $0.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/YmbOfBlKGDy7K39ngf5m0vrXG8gK-gCORC1ybbtMVJa63MX1SPjtxi4jMQmRrcazgw=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>NOAA Weather Unofficial (Pro)</h1>
              <span>com.nstudio.weatherhere</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.nstudio.weatherhere
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Granite Apps
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $1.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HB1NQpjlT21nGLFXCc5lLHXqtft9CHNq8nLW16DDJF_d61_9CVYbEuRfrYGfIXI8V2Y=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Password Manager SafeInCloud™</h1>
              <span>com.safeincloud</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.safeincloud
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              SafeInCloud
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $2.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/twhd0ckGPSETQH7TDkiYvrJr-FKQ-YP1Bll1_-Dk-1Bx4YdJJ1HwinVhHk6uy_YYEe8=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Talon for Twitter</h1>
              <span>com.klinker.android.twitter_l</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.klinker.android.twitter_l
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Luke Klinker
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $1.49
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/UgItAs4ckdGHTXTVWNQ0NNrWy9rh6ya4BrjwAUPMsgMpwOI2NQ7N0zvfQ8eyb78NzHE=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Watch Face - Minimal &amp; Elegant</h1>
              <span>com.stmp.minimalface</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.stmp.minimalface
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Studio eXtreme
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $1.59
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OZQhEH8B9PNGPkOlx714tIK0mEjMBHUEoJdb2bqUY01i9SKh8iI66j9RMRRzYCvKpYc=w340" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              <h1>Weather Live</h1>
              <span>com.apalon.weatherlive</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              com.apalon.weatherlive
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              Apalon Apps
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
              $0.99
            </div>
          </div>
        
      </div>
```